# QT QGraphicsScene with QLabel and QPixmap

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qlabel, pixmap

I have a QGraphicsView, in that I have a QGraphicsScene, in that I have a QLabel and I set a .png picture as QPixmap into the QLabel. The .png is set in background.qrc resource file.
My QLabel's size is 600x400. Without the pixmap it's okay, the QGraphicsScene's size is 600x400 too. But when I set the pixmap to the QLabel and scale it, it fails.
The QLabel's size is the same, the pixmap is scaled well within the QLabel and only visible within it, but the QGraphicsScene adopts the real size of the QPixmap, which is 720x720. So the QLabel is visible with the QPixmap in it's correct size, but there is a gray place around it, since the scene is bigger.
How can I fix this and make it work? I want the QGraphicScene to stay on the size of the QLabel.

Here's the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsView *myView = new QGraphicsView(this);
    QGraphicsScene *myScene= new QGraphicsScene();
    QLabel *myLabel= new QLabel();
    myLabel->setBaseSize(QSize(600, 400));
    myLabel->resize(myLabel->baseSize());
    myLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    QPixmap pixmapBackground(":/new/cross.png");
    myLabel->setPixmap(pixmapBackground);
    myScene->addWidget(myLabel);
    myView->setScene(myScene);
    setCentralWidget(myView);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `QGraphicsPixmapItem` instead? It is more lightweight and easy to control.

Comment: It's not working for me. I must make it with a QLabel and a QPixmap.

Comment: @Alex And what do you mean by "not working for you" ? Maybe we can solve this issue.

Comment: I mean QGraphicsPixmapItem is not a solution for me. I must solve it with QLabel and QPixmap and fix the QGraphicsScene's size this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example code, you don't set the scene's size. You can do this with a call to [setSceneRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop). As the documentation states, when the rect is not set: -

> If unset, or if set to a null QRectF, sceneRect() will return the largest bounding rect of all items on the scene since the scene was created (i.e., a rectangle that grows when items are added to or moved in the scene, but never shrinks).

Therefore without setting the scene rect, when the label is added to the scene, its size is changing, as in this example

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView *myView = new QGraphicsView;
    QGraphicsScene *myScene= new QGraphicsScene();

    // constrain the QGraphicsScene size
    // without this, the defect as stated in the question is visible
    myScene->setSceneRect(0,0,600,400); 

    QLabel *myLabel= new QLabel;    
    myLabel->setBaseSize(QSize(600, 400));
    myLabel->resize(myLabel->baseSize());
    myLabel->setScaledContents(true);

    QPixmap pixmapBackground(720, 720);
    pixmapBackground.fill(QColor(0, 255, 0)); // green pixmap

    myLabel->setPixmap(pixmapBackground);
    myScene->addWidget(myLabel);
    myView->setScene(myScene);
    myView->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This should result in the correct scene size, as demonstrated here: -

[image]

As discussed in the comments, the example code above works as expected on OS X, but there still appears to be an issue when executing on Windows 10.

Comment: I tried this, right before adding the QPixmap:
`myScene->setSceneRect(0, 0, myLabel->width(), myLabel->height());`
But the result is the same.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example. As you can see here, if *setSceneRect* isn't called, the effect you're seeing is the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, but as I said it's not working!
[link](https://postimg.org/image/lct8jh181/)
This is the result of your code, copied and pasted. It appers to be good only as long as I don't change the windows size or the view's scale... Which, of course, I will do, so this little problem will be visible immediately. But thanks for taking the time to try to help me!!

Comment: What platform are you running on? I've added the result to my example code, which is running on OS X.

Comment: Windows 10. I see your result, it's the same by me at the default window size. But if I make it fullscreen, it shows what I linked. Did you try it with fullscreen window?

Comment: As I see it doesn't solve this issue, only hides it and only if I don't manipulate the window size or the view scale any more.

Comment: It's different full screen on OS X, I don't have the grey background, just the scene in the centre of the screen, which suggests this is an issue specific to Windows.

Comment: What a pity... Anyway, thanks for the help! I'll mark your answer as solution, but please make a note that it works for sure only on OS X.